# Need help with proof by contradiction of implication.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, foundations

Question reads:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall m \in \mathbb{N}, (n^4 + n^2 + 1 \ne m^2)$$

In english, this reads: for every n and m in the set of natural numbers, $n^4 + n^2 + 1$ does not equal a perfect square.

I would like to prove by contradiction because it seems like the most obvious route, but have gotten stuck and need help. My goal is to negate the implication above and either prove or disprove:
$$n^4 + n^2 + 1 = m^2$$
As follows:

$$\sim(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall m \in \mathbb{N} ,(n^4 + n^2 + 1 \ne m^2)) = \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \sim(\forall m \in \mathbb{N}, (n^4 + n^2 + 1 \ne m^2))$$
$$\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \sim(\forall m \in \mathbb{N}, (n^4 + n^2 + 1 \ne m^2)) = \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists m \in \mathbb{N}, \sim(n^4 + n^2 + 1 \ne m^2)$$
$$\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists m \in \mathbb{N}, \sim(n^4 + n^2 + 1 \ne m^2) = \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists m \in \mathbb{N}, (n^4 + n^2 + 1 = m^2)$$
My goal is now to prove or disprove:
$$n^4 + n^2 + 1 = m^2$$
By factoring:
$$n^2(n^2 + 1) + 1 = m^2$$
$$n^2(n^2 + 1) = m^2 - 1$$
Clearly, both of the the items on the left of the equation can divide the right hand side, but I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $n^4+n^2+1=(n^2+1)^2-n^2$ is the difference of two squares.

Comment: The question in the header seems very different from the question in the body.

Comment: Hint: can you have $(2m)^2-3=(2N^2+1)^2.$

Comment: Hint;  the square root of your number lies between $N^2$ and $N^2+1$.

Comment: Hi all - sorry, I edited the question so that the formatting is better, I made a mistake with my indentation. Please take a look.

Comment: Please correct the header so that it corresponds to the question you mean to ask.

Comment: Corrected header @lulu

Comment: Well, I think you mean $\neq$ perfect square.

Comment: Why does your title say to prove $N^4 + N^2 + 1$ *IS* a perfect square.

Comment: I was going to prove the implication by contradiction, so by proving $ \exists n,m \in \mathbb{N}  (n^4 + n^2 + 1 = m^2)$ , I've disproved the negation of the first implication and proved the implication.

Answer (score 7):

$$(n^2)^2<n^4+n^2+1<(n^2+1)^2$$
so that $n^4+n^2+1$ is between two consecutive squares.

Comment: This helped me. I allowed $(m_1) = n^2$ and $(m_2) = n^2 + 1 = m_1 + 1$. It is thusly clear that $(m_1)^2 = n^4 < n^4 + n^2 + 1 < n^4 + 2n^2 + 1 = (m_1 + 1)^2$. We have arrived at the desired contradiction. How can I generalize $m_1 = n^2$ to all $m \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Why do you need $m_1$ or $m_2$ and all?  Just say: if $m^2 = n^4 + n^2 + 1$ then $(n^2)^2 < m^2 < (n^2+1)^2$ so $n < m < n+1$ and there's no integer $m$ between two consecutive integers.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it:

$n^4 + n^2 + 1 = m^2$

$n^4 + n^2 + (1-m^2) = 0$

$n^2 =\frac {-1 \pm \sqrt{1 -4(1-m)^2}}2$

$n^2 = -\frac 12 \pm \frac {\sqrt{4m^2 -3}}2$

Then $4m^2 -3$ must be a perfect square (or else this is irrational).  And $4m^2 = (2m)^2$ is also a perfect square.

Are there any two perfect squares that are exactly $3$ apart?

Well, the difference between any two consecutive squares, $(k+1)^2, k^2$ is $(k+1)^2 - k^2 = 2k + 1$.

So if $(2m)^2 - k^2 =3$ then $2m > k$ and $3= (2m)^2 - k^2\ge (k+1)^2 - k^2 = 2k + 1$.

So $k \le 1$.

If $k = 0$ then $(2m)^2 = 3$ which is impossible.

So $k =1$ and $(2m)^2 -3 =1$ so $m =1$.

and therefore

....

$n^2 =-\frac 12 \pm \frac {4m^2 - 3}2 = $

$-\frac 12 \pm \frac {4*1^2 -3}2 = 0, -1$

$n^2 = -1 $ is impossible so $n = 0$.

Which, if you accept that $0$ is a natural number is perfectly acceptable.  But as you probably *don't* accept that $0$ is a natural number there are no solution.